# Overwriting a file in perl

Tags: perl

How would I go about overwriting a file with an array using Perl?

My file looks like this:

```
username1
comment
comment
comment
username2
comment
comment
username3
comment
comment
comment
...
```

What I do is load the lines into an array first. Then go through the array adding lines to a new array. When it finds the line of the user I want to add the comment to it will trigger a flag that makes it add the comment on the next incrementation of the loop. Then after that it just adds the rest of the lines to the array. What I want to do then it use the new array to overwrite the file. That is where I am stuck.

```
sub AddComment() {

  my $username = shift;    # the username to find
  my $comment  = shift;    # the comment to add
  chomp($comment);
  chomp($username);

  open my $COMMENTS, '<', "comments.txt" or die "$!";    #open the comments file
  my @lines = <$COMMENTS>;              #Make an array of the files lines

  my @NewCommentsFile;                  # make an array to store new file lines
  my $addCommentNow = 0;                # flag to know when to add comment

  for my $line (@lines) {
    if ($line eq $username) {           # if this line is the username
      $addCommentNow = 1;               # set flag that next line you add comment
      push(@NewCommentsFile, $line);    # add this line to new array
    }
    elsif ($addCommentNow eq 1) {       # if the flag is 1 then do this
      push(@NewCommentsFile, $comment); # add the comment to the array
      $addCommentNow = 0;               # reset flag
    }
    else {
      push(@NewCommentsFile, $line);       #add line to array
    }
  }

  open my $fh, '>', "comments.txt" or die "Cannot open output.txt: $!";

  # Loop over the array
  foreach (@NewCommentsFile) {
    print $fh "$_";    # Print each entry in our new array to the file
  }

  close $fh;
}
```

Comment: Don't use file prototypes (the parentheses in your `sub AddComment()` declaration) unless you know what you are doing. Once you know what you are doing, you still won't use file prototypes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You `chomp` `$username`, but not `$line`, so `$username` will never equal `$line`.
2. You `chomp` the new comment to be added, but in your final loop you are printing without a newline. So, any new comment that you print would be file prepended onto whatever line follows it.
3. Your `elsif ($addCommentNow eq 1) {` will throw away the current buffer or do other odd things depending on the input.

Try this modified code (that only addresses those three concerns):

```
for my $line (@lines) {
    chomp $line;
    push(@NewCommentsFile, $line);
    push(@NewCommentsFile, $comment) if $line eq $username;
}
open my $fh, '>', "comments.txt" or die "Cannot open output.txt: $!";
foreach (@NewCommentsFile) {
    print $fh "$_\n"; # Print each entry in our new array to the file
}
close($fh);
```

Comment: Thank you, Your way is much more concise.

Comment: @R00059159 Note your program does not appear to handle the situation where a comment matches a username.

Comment: @codnodder - Indeed, and this was brought to the OP's attention [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20384920/writing-text-to-textarea-from-a-text-file-in-perl/20385941#20385941).

Comment: Now that Kenosis brought my attention to the other post and I see this is for a web app, I want to point out that the snippet I posted does not address the obvious issue of concurrent file updates.

Comment: Good point.  Although there are other options, I think using [DBM::Deep](http://search.cpan.org/~rkinyon/DBM-Deep-2.0010/lib/DBM/Deep.pod) to maintain a HoA w/username as key and comments as array elements would provide a viable option for the OP--and it does provide a locking mechanism.  The OP's already maintaining a separate file for usernames, so such a hash would take of both usernames and comments.

Answer (score 2):

Don't open the file two times.
Just use seek to go to the beginning of it:

```
seek($COMMENTS, 0, 0);
```

And, of course, open it for read/write (use `"+<"`).

Comment: I did this but it does not seem to add the comment?

Comment: @Igor, I imagine you meant to include `truncate` after your `seek`?